# Create a MongoDB Atlas serverless cluster using CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to create a serverless MongoDB Atlas cluster using CDK and i have this error:

> Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [MongoDB::Atlas::Project, MongoDB::Atlas::DatabaseUser, MongoDB::Atlas::ProjectIpAccessList, MongoDB::Atlas::ServerlessInstance]

By the way another thing i don't understand, is why the property `serverlessProps` can be required, if none of its properties is required.

I don't understand either how so many props could be optional (almost all of them)

[Here is the documentation](https://constructs.dev/packages/awscdk-resources-mongodbatlas/v/3.1.0/api/AtlasServerlessBasicProps?lang=typescript) i based on

Here is the code

```js
new AtlasServerlessBasic(this, "Database", {
  projectProps: {
    orgId: "5aba***********",
  },
  serverlessProps: {}
});
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/mongodb/awscdk-resources-mongodbatlas/tree/main/examples